# I m getting SQL state as null and closed statement while trying to fetch some data

Tags: java, sql-server

Actually i want to fetch some data from data base using rs.getString("ServiceType") but before getting it in that i'm getting exception as SQL state as null and the statement closed.And vendor code is 17009. I'm unable to get what is the error.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Add some code and Error log for better understanding the question.

Comment: After removing the close statement line and the releaseConn method which was called just after executing the query the problem was solved .

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
yourConn = connection.createStatement();
String command ="select * from table1";
ResultSet rs = yourConn.executeQuery(command);
rs.last();
rs.next();
```

Seeing as how there isn't any code (as of posting this) I have simplified one of my own applications.

It seems as though you are not closing your resultset correctly. As a general rule, surround all SQL in java with a try-catch, and add a `finally` clause to close all resources.